# Knock Out - JS split

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, pager

We developed a WEB based application using Knock out and Pager JS. We are almost to the end of the project. We have only one view model that serves the data binding for all data elements shown on UI screen. We are looking out for the options to split the JS files to make it more efficient and readable. Since we have only one view model that serves the whole data binding, its easier for us to call same methods for different actions using self.methodName();. My Questions are below,

1) If we are going to split up the View models into multiple files,  how do we invoke a method from one view model to another view model.

2) I was checking abt the namespace to split the files using knockout, but not sure how far it works?

3) Some recommendation using require js, I seen some examples.. but not sure whether that will resolve the issue.

We are apply the databinding like below,

```
window.VM = new viewModel();

    ko.applyBindings(window.VM);
```

4) If the content of the data is been shared with mutliple screens, how do we bind for each div.. for example, if I want to show the contact detail screen in Contact Detail and also subset of contact Detail information... How do we acheive it.. Based on my understanding, the databinding applies to a div element.. If I want to show the same data on two different screen, how we will acheive this...

Sorry for asking everything in one question..

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: Yes i too wish to do it. My code is becoming measy as i have everything in one file. Interesting to see answers for this.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you have to read about PubSub concept, which is easy implementable with KO.
E.g. http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html